# Save method rolls back and returns nil when valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am having trouble with Rails' `save` method; it seems to be failing when it should, but not succeeding when it should.

I have a `Claim` model, that can be saved with any `Status`, but if it is to be submitted (`status_id == 5`) then the terms and conditions have to be accepted.

```
validates :terms_and_conditions, :acceptance => {:accept => true, :if => :submitted?}

def submitted? # simplified for this example
  status_id == 5
end
```

However, I am also storing the *time* that the terms were accepted (under db field `tnc_accepted_at`), and defining `terms_and_conditions` as the presence of this field. (This bit works fine, I'm just not sure if it's relevant to my problem.)

```
def terms_and_conditions
  tnc_accepted_at.present?
end

def terms_and_conditions=(bool) # browser will pass '0' or '1'
  self.tnc_accepted_at = bool.in?([false, nil, 0, '', '0']) ? nil : DateTime.now
end
```

But here's the rub. The claim starts off in this state:

```
claim
 => #<Claim id: 51, tnc_accepted_at: nil, status_id: 4>
claim.valid?
 => true
```

Then I try to submit it:

```
claim.update_attributes! :status_id => 5
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ClaimItem Load (1.5ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
  Status Load (0.6ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Terms and conditions must be accepted
```

... which is perfect, but when I try to correct the error:

```
claim.update_attributes! :terms_and_conditions => true
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ClaimItem Load (1.1ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE "claims" --blah blah blah
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => nil
```

... which is just weird! And I've noticed that I also get this any time I try to save the record, under whatever set of circumstances (using `save`, `save!`, `update_attributes`, `update_attributes!`, `:tnc_accepted_at => DateTime.now`, it doesn't matter) - if it's *valid*, it rolls back and returns nil; if it's *invalid*, the error is raised as you would expect.

Comment: Versions: rails 3.1.0; pg 0.11; "PostgreSQL 9.1.5 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3, 64-bit" (Ubuntu 12.04 'Precise Pangolin'). Can't think of anything else that would be relevant.

Comment: NB. The reason I'm not putting a `presence` validator directly on `tnc_accepted_at` is because that field isn't in the view; instead, I have a `terms_and_conditions` check box, and I want the error to appear against that.

Comment: Also when trying this on a new `claim`, the `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` fields _do_ get populated, and Rails figures it isn't a new record any more. Hopefully that will help pinpoint where the problem is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally it's something really simple, after I spent an entire day on it...

So it seems `update_attributes` only works properly on records that have **already been saved**.

```
> claim
 => #<Claim id: 51, tnc_accepted_at: nil, status_id: 4>
> claim.valid?
 => true
#=========
> claim.save # This makes all the difference!
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Claim Load (0.4ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
   (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "claims" --blah blah blah
   (14.8ms)  COMMIT
 => true
#=========
> claim.update_attributes! :status_id => 5
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ClaimItem Load (1.5ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
  Status Load (0.6ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Terms and conditions must be accepted
# ... just as expected.
> claim.update_attributes! :terms_and_conditions => true
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ClaimItem Load (0.8ms)  SELECT --blah blah blah
   (0.8ms)  UPDATE "claims" --blah blah blah
   (11.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
# ... hooray!
```

Comment: Although, weirdly, `claim.terms_and_conditions = true; claim.status_id = 5; claim.save` (starting with a valid `claim`) still rolls back and returns nil. At least I've found _some_ way to make it work, though.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this question is to old?

I think the problem is the `"new record"` flag (as you suggested). If a new record is saved, the `"new record"` is set to false, good, but if there is a rollback, the `"new record"` will still have the value false, like other populated columns in the save will remain their values.
And if a new save is tried (with correct values) the `save` method in Rails will do an db-update instead of a db-insert because `"new record"` is false.

I noticed this in a very old version of Rails, thought that it would be fixed by now. I fixed it with this method in ActiveRecord::Base (Rails must still be using @new_record internally for this to work)

```
def try_reset_new_record!
  if ! self.new_record? &&
      ( ! self.id || ! self.class.find_by_id(self.id) )
    @new_record = true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another reason that an ActiveRecord `save` method would return nil is if it is being mocked. Something like `expect(modelInstance).to receive(:save)`

Comment: thanks for this answer. I'm working on upgrading a legacy app with test code that does this (unfortunately), but fixing this resolved the issue!